# responsive image with object-fit:cover

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to frame the image, getting just the `width:300px;` of the image visible and the rest of the width invisible. I have been working with `object-fit:cover` and `overflow: hidden`. But I haven't been able to do it while still having the image responsive `(width: 100%)`,scaling in size.

Here is the html code for the image:

```
<div id="pgc-1397-2-0" class="panel-grid-cell">
<div id="panel-1397-2-0-0" class="so-panel widget widget_sow-image panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="2">
::before
<div class="so-widget-sow-image so-widget-sow-image-default-bf8d3ff3bedb">
<h3 class="widget-title">KRAGEN</h3>
<div class="sow-image-container">
<img src="http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31.jpeg"width="800" height="450" srcset="http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31-300x169.jpeg 300w, http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31-768x432.jpeg 768w, http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31.jpeg 800w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" title="KRAGEN" class="so-widget-image"
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the webpage:

```
http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/
```

Here is a picture of how I want to frame the picture:

[image]

and this is what I want for result:

[image]

I have made fiddle here: `https:www.jsfiddle.net/q2yrqvxv/5/`

Comment: Using `object-fit:cover` you have to need define `width and height` for parent `div` not `img` .

Answer (score 0):

Control Image Aspect Ratio Using CSS `object-fit` and `object-position` properties allow you to scale images and videos, much like you could with `background-size` and `background-position`.

Moreover [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) you will get documentation and example

```css
img {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 75vh;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 0;
}


/* Demo styles only */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg">
</div>
```