# CSS Responsive image with viewport max height

Tags: css

I would like to have a responsive image with 80vw width for example. I want it to fit entirely on the screen and **keep the proportions** (if the height is too large, the width should decrease)

```
img {
width: 80vw;
max-height: 80vh;}
```

Comment: `object-fit: cover;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `object-fit: cover;`
and look at the same question please which is below, (btw of course you can do the same thing with `background-image;` and `background-size: cover;` if you want to use a bc-image instead of `<img>` tag)
heres the link:
[responsive image with object-fit:cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474443/responsive-image-with-object-fitcover)